# How to place coordinates > 100.0f in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

When I place coordinates like this:

```
display(){
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 360.0f);
    drawTeapot();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The teapot is not visible and I want it visible at 360.0f.

I am using this for init,

```
init()
{
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluPerspective(45, width/height, -1000, 1000);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `gluLookAt()` to ensure the camera is facing the teapot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a case placing coordinates > 100.0f. For starters your furstrum is wrong as the zNear value should be > 0. There is no negative region of a viewing frustrum :).

The translation you are doing on the ModelView matrix is the wrong way. i.e invert the z translation to -360.0f.

[See here for more information on OpenGL axis](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_anglestoaxes.html). If you translate an object n-units to the left, from the camera's point of view you have moved it n-units to the right.

Comment: So how do I add a custom axis and a coordinate system so that I can represent 360.0f sir?

Comment: What If I use glOrtho() for this ?

Comment: You don't need a custom axis, you are doing everything correct, just that you are (a) creating a frustrum which is actually half the size of what you want.. use glPerspective(45.0, width/height, 0.1f, 1000.0f); and (b) drawing the teapot behind your camera. Thats why it has been suggested to invert the z component of the translation in the modelview matrix.

If you place a bit of geom at (0,0,1), and the camera at (0,0,0), you will be looking the wrong way, instead...
place the geom at (0,0,-1) and camera at (0,0,0).

Comment: There is no far clipping happening to stop you seeing your teapot. Your frustrum will be able to view your teapot.

If you want to apply a 'custom' axis, its best to represent this as matrix transformation from the current world coordinate systme into your own system, this would be a matrix you apply in your modelview matrix (glMultMatrixf)

Comment: Ortho will simply give you an Orthographic projection rather than Perspective, ortho is certainly easier to work with when seting up GL scenes this way as there is no perspective distortion. Orthogrpahic frustrum would be cuboid, perspective is trapezoidal

Comment: I will choose your answer as the best answer if you look at this picture and answer:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLFPYesfxD8MDgzMlN2bkZucDQ/view?usp=sharing These are the coordinates that I have to implement in opengl.

Comment: Please I am begging you.

Comment: :) Sorry just went out for lunch.  You have all the correct code, simply negate the z component of the translation to see your teapot. If you are using those cooridnates from the image you supplied, you may not see it because it is -45.5814. So you need to translate your camera -y. All the points in the image would be within the frustrum you supply (glPerspective(45,width/height,-1000.0,1000.0)) or for ortho glOrtho(52.6977, 369.552, -45.5814, 245.581, 0.1, 700.0) will create a frustrum which is bounding box of points you supplied. Also translate the camera -360. glTranslatef(0,0,-360.0f).

Comment: P.S Without the translation of the camera, the camera will be inside the teapot (you would see the interior of it, providing GL was not setup to perform back-face culling), with the translation, the camera will be outside the teapot and so you will see the exterior of the teapot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I am choosing you as the best answer now.

Answer (score 0):

1. your zNear plane shouldn't be negative 
   gluPerspective(45, width/height, 0.1, 1000);
2. have you tried placing the teapot at -360 ? . are you sure your view is looking towards +z and not -z
3. whats your scaling of the teapot?. Maybe it's just too tiny to be seen so far away

Comment: how can i be sure that I am looking at -z?

Comment: I did like 100.0f for scaling teapot.